# Wait until a delegate is called

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task, begininvoke

I have an asynchronous class with a `StartProcessing()` method, that raises an `int ResultReady()` event when it has finished processing. `StartProcessing()` takes very little time.

I want to call this class synchronously. My pseudo-code should be something like:

1. Call StartProcessing()
2. Wait/sleep until result is ready
3. Return result

What design pattern is best for this? Can you please point me to a code example?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One simple way of doing this is with a [`ManualResetEvent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.manualresetevent.aspx) which the event handler and the waiting code both have access to. Call [`Set`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.eventwaithandle.set.aspx) from the event handler, and [`WaitOne`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58195swd.aspx) (or an overload with a timeout) from the waiting thread. Note that this can't be done on an STA thread, so you can't do it within a WinForms thread (which should always be STA) - but you shouldn't be waiting within a UI thread anyway.

Something like this:

```
var async = new AsyncClass();
var manualEvent = new ManualResetEvent();
async.ResultReady += args => manualEvent.Set();
async.StartProcessing();
manualEvent.WaitOne();
```

Comment: When I do this it seems that ResultReady is never called. I suspect that the delegate is set to start in the same thread which is blocked. However the delegate in my case is called from a framework that I do not have control of. Hence I never get pass WaitOne. Do you have any ideas on how to solve it?

Comment: @dynamokaj: Delegates aren't "set to start" in any particular thread. The framework you're using may decide to raise an event in a particular thread... but basically we can't help you without more information. I suggest you ask a new question with more details.